# UIImageView+Afnetworking doesn't Work Properly

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, afnetworking-2

I Have copied the contents of file from [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h) and created a UIImageView+AFNetworking.h and imported in my implementation file

Now When I Write the following code i get this error but when i remove the block of code then everything works fine.

I want to display image in a custom table cell.The url of image i am grabbing Through JSON

```
NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dictArray objectForKey:@"image"]]];
[cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest placeholderImage:nil
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                   NSLog(@"success");
                                   cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
                                   cell.thumbnailImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                                   cell.thumbnailImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
                                   [cell setNeedsLayout];// To update the cell {if not using this, your image is not showing over cell.}
                               }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                   NSLog(@"Failure");}];
```

Here is the screen shot of the error

It Crashes after loading 
[image]

Comment: see you missing closer of [cell.thumbnailImageView setIma.....

Comment: u were missed the **;** in end of the block

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated my question now i get this fatal error

Comment: @HuyNghia Now my app Crashes

Comment: try this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/303

Comment: i am not able to get what to do and where to write this please suggest me @HuyNghia

Comment: Make sure this method `-setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure` is real. Use Command+Click to see its implementation. Your app crashed because that method didn't exist

Comment: see this image to add flags  -ObjC and -all_load :http://quickblox.com/developers/File:IOS_SDK_objCflag.png

Comment: @VietHung this method exists as i imported the AFNetworking+UiImage file

Comment: @UnicoRahul: you should try to use CocoaPod to add `AFNetworking` into your project http://cocoapods.org . It's easy and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using afnetworking  You can just use dispatch method

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
      NSString *url = [indexDic objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        cellImg.image = image;

    });
});

return cell;

 }
```